# AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'simple_marker' in folium

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps, data-visualization, folium

Code is below

```
import folium
import pandas as pd
 
SF_COORDINATES = (37.76, -122.45)
crimedata = pd.read_csv('SFPD_Incidents_2015.csv')
 
# for speed purposes
MAX_RECORDS = 1000
  
# create empty map zoomed in on San Francisco
map = folium.Map(location=SF_COORDINATES, zoom_start=12)
 
# add a marker for every record in the filtered data, use a clustered view
for each in crimedata[0:MAX_RECORDS].iterrows():
    map.simple_marker(
        location = [each[1]['Y'],each[1]['X']], 
        clustered_marker = True)
  
display(map)
```

Got error:

> AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'simple_marker' in
> folium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can directly check [here](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/1019), `simple_marker` has been removed.

Use:

1. [`folium.Marker()`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html#folium.map.Marker) to create a simple stock Leaflet marker on the map, and
2. [`folium.plugins.MarkerCluster()`](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/plugins.html#folium.plugins.MarkerCluster) for Marker Clustering.

Comment: How to update the markers location when drag and drop?